# iOS Memory Management on iPad Mini

Tags: ios, memory-management

I'm new to objective C and iOS i'm facing memory problem using an iPad mini,

I use a nag-based app, when I want to push a `UIVIewController` on the stack i use :

```
MyUIViewController *aController = [MyUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyUIViewController" bundle:nil];
```

when I use the new XCode 5 Memory debug navigator and that I push a new controller on the stack I see the memory growing up, then when I use :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I assume that with ARC the controller is released, but the memory never goes down. Same thing when I dismiss a `PopController`.

I do not understand, is there a way to release this controller in the memory so my app will run perfectly?

I know I have to release things that are not on the screen when I receive a memory warning
but in that case I'm stuck because everything I need is on the screen...

Comment: What do you do in this controller ?

Comment: well it is not a single controller, loading images, loading sounds, network request . . . but evrything is on the screen. Yes i'm using retina images with [named] on a non retina because the app will be to big to be uploaded on 3G/4G 50 Mb limit. if i remove view from my top controller i have to add them on the viewWillAppear ?

Comment: Are you actually having problems as a result of memory usage (such as iOS terminating your app), or do you just see the number going up and you're worried?

Comment: No the app stops i have a warning on Xcode :Terminated due to Memory Pressure

Comment: `[UIImage imageNamed:@""];` doesn't release images from memory, that's probably your issue. Use `imageWithData` instead

Comment: ok thanks i'll give a try. You mean i load image from bundle with NSData and then set Image with imageWithData ?

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a couple of tools in order to help diagnose your problem, both in Instruments. You can use the Memory Leak tool to see if your view controller is actually leaking memory, you can also use the Memory Allocation tool to create heapshots to see if you are having a problem with abandoned memory. [Here is a good tutorial about using Instruments for debugging.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided source code, but I have a few things I recommend when running into this issue:

First, implement the `-(void)dealloc` method on the `UIViewController` you are popping and see if it gets called (place a breakpoint in it) when you perform the actual pop. If it doesn't what is happening is that this `UIViewController` is getting retained by some other object.

Use the Static Analyzer to check if it finds issue in your code:

[image: Analyze!]

Also make sure you are not running into a retain cycle.

For blocks:

Blocks retain all objects in their scope, unless you explicitly tell them not to. If your object retains this block as well, you will run into a retain cycle. To prevent this, you generally want to create a weak pointer to self.

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    _weak id weakSelf = self;
    self.block = ^{
        [weakSelf doSomething];  // retain cycle free!
    };
}
```

For composition:

You will also run into a retain cycle if you have an object which retains another object, which in turn retains the first one. For example:

```
@interface ObjectA : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) ObjectB *objectB;

@end

@implementation

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.objectB = [[ObjectB alloc] initWithObjectA:self]; // self.objectB gets retained
    }

    return self;
}

@end

@interface ObjectB : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) ObjectA *objectA; // the strong directive will cause a retain cycle, this should be weak

- (id)initWithAnObjectA:(ObjectA *)objectA;

@end

@implementation ObjectB

- (id)initWithAnObjectA:(ObjectA *)objectA;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.objectA = objectA; // self.objectA gets retained, leading to a retain cycle
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks i'll give a try, how can i be sure i'm not running into a retain cycle (i'm using ARC)

Comment: when do i know to use strong or weak ?

Comment: You use strong when you need the object to be available at any time. Weak or assign is used when you assume it will be available (Use weak for objects and assign for structures or data types). In my example, you can assume objectB's objectA will be available any time, because without it, objectB doesn't exists. Hope that makes sense. :P

Comment: ok, but does it make a difference when the UIViewController gets poped ? When the view disappear i have to set my strong reference to nil ? 
Sorry if i'm a dumb.

Comment: ARC handles that for you automatically if you use weak. (setting the reference to nil). When your view controller gets popped, it should get deallocated assuming it's retain count reaches 0. If it's not getting deallocated is because you are retaining it elsewhere.

Comment: and if i want to know where i'm retaining it i have to use instrument ?

Comment: Yeah. You could check for Leaks in Instruments and inspect the stack trace (right pane) to see where the problem lies.

Comment: so complicated, all objects in the UIViewController must be released and everything would be perfect.

Comment: Thank you very much pedro.m you helped me a lot. Wish you the best.

Comment: I'm using custom delegate to load data custom object i use :@property (nonatomic, assign) id <CoursModelDelegate> delegate;
may be that no ?

Comment: It looks fine. However I would recommend using `weak` instead of `assign`. `weak` automatically sets your pointer to nil after it gets deallocated. Try updating your question with more details on the implementation of your objects, unless it's too much code. :P

Comment: yea it's too much code, i always use strong instead of weak for everything (button, objects...) i made a find replace for weak but now the app does not launch anymore !

Comment: You don't want to do that. Use individual criteria for when to use strong vs weak. Try reading more on [Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html), it's important to have a solid grasp on it, even when using ARC.

Answer (score -1):

Use autorelease view controller when add it to navigation hierarhy

```
MyUIViewController *aController = [[MyUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyUIViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aController animated:YES];
```

Comment: He is using ARC, so autorelease is not permitted

Comment: Yea i'm using ARC . . .